# Is the White color good for wall paint for rooms that are not exposed to the sun?

Tags: walls, painting, paint

I am trying to find which is the best color for my corridor passage, because my corridor doesn't have enough light from the sun, Is white color(degree one) good for paint wall for Internal rooms/corridor passage that are not exposed to the sun directly? 
on the following my corridor

[image]

Comment: This is really an opinion question. I believe white would be the best color as darker colors tend to not feel as bright. Another possibility is to use florescent or led lighting with a color frequency above 5K it is amazing how much more perceived light with a higher color at the same lumens.

Comment: @EdBeal Do you think true color degree 1 is good more than white degree ?

Comment: They both play a role white reflects where black absorbs a warmer color tends to appear lighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern residential paint is white or an off-white.

I know the colorist is talking about blues, yellows, greens, pinks etc. -- but it's all pretty much white.  You can't go wrong.

If you really wanted OSHA safety orange, they do sell that in paint, but nobody wants that in a house.  Or on a house.  If you painted a house that, you'd hear from the HOA or city manager.

If you want the brightest white that ever was, ask the paint company about the highest reflectivity paint they make, typically a "snow white"... whatever... all those names are made up.

Comment: Snow white. .. this is what I was  searching  . It is the highest reflective. .